# object literal of module definition with anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm reading about jQuery and when i came to this article then i thought i would then use an object literal:
http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/beware-anonymous-functions/

but then when reading this article:
http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/dont-repeat-yourself/

i kind of got confused.

It says that anonymous functions are difficult to debug, but then in the second article you get private variables and methods which you probably want instead of having all variables and methods public, but you then apparently have to use a self-invoking anonymous function anyway.

Clearly i need private and public variables and methods in modules, but i dont want my code to be unnecessarily hard to debug because of the use of anonymous functions, so i find these two articles a little conflicting.. or will you actually get the name of the function when using the module pattern here?

Comment: Anonymous functions are very useful. Note that the first article says "everywhere". Using a self-invoking anonymous function attached to `$(document).ready` to set up your environment is a fairly standard practice, and not particularly hard to debug.

Comment: Ok, but what about a module ? You are basically putting every variable and method inside of a self-invoking anonymous function. Some uses of it may be fine like you say, but what about the module pattern where you are defining all your code in it

Comment: You could have just one anonymous, self-invoking function that sets up your entire environment. In it you could initialize all of your other modules explicitly, by calling their named initialization functions.

Comment: I appriciate you taking the time to comment but that doesnt answer my question. I'm not setting up any environment here, im creatin a regular module, and i dont want to do any hacks. I find it strange that they first recommend an object literal because anonymous functions are hard to understand, but then say that it should be use when creating a module.

Comment: The "beware" article needs a bit more nuance. It says that anonymous functions "bound everywhere" are a problem. It would be better if it said "used injudiciously". Yes, they can be used in a way that can be hard to read and hard to debug. However, they can (and should) be used in many places because they in fact make reading and debugging much easier. The DRY article is a perfect example of how anonymous functions serve a very good purpose. I've set up [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GreatBigBore/k8CP4/) fiddle to demonstrate a couple of common initialization techniques you'll see out there.

Comment: Sorry if I'm helping much. Usually you would get a thousand responders on a question like this. Not sure why yours isn't getting more notice. You might consider posting it on programmers.stackexchange, which is more about conceptual questions like this.